# Nuitka error when compiling PyQt5 script "implicit module sip" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, nuitka

I'm trying to compile a Python script using Nuitka: `nuitka --recurse-all main.py` which then returns the error:

```
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py:99: Cannot find 'cryptography' in package 'requests' as absolute import (tried cryptography).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py:41: Cannot find 'urlparse' in package 'requests' as absolute import (tried urlparse).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py:42: Cannot find 'urllib2' in package 'requests' as absolute import (tried urllib2).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py:43: Cannot find 'cookielib' in package 'requests' as absolute import (tried cookielib).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py:44: Cannot find 'Cookie' in package 'requests' as absolute import (tried Cookie).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\ordered_dict.py:11: Cannot find '_abcoll' in package 'urllib3.packages' as absolute import (tried _abcoll).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\ssl_match_hostname\__init__.py:13: Cannot find 'backports.ssl_match_hostname' in package 'urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname' as absolute import (tried backports.ssl_match_hostname).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\backports:1: Cannot find '_frozen_importlib_external' in package 'backports' as absolute import (tried _frozen_importlib_external).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\socks.py:27: Cannot find 'socks' in package 'urllib3.contrib' as absolute import (tried socks).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:28: Cannot find 'packages.six.moves' in package 'urllib3' 1 package level up (tried urllib3.packages.six.moves,packages.six.moves).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\queue.py:3: Cannot find 'packages.six.moves' in package 'urllib3' 2 package levels up (tried urllib3.packages.six.moves).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py:4: Cannot find 'packages.six.moves.urllib.parse' in package 'urllib3' 1 package level up (tried urllib3.packages.six.moves.urllib.parse,packages.six.moves.urllib.parse).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py:4: Cannot find 'packages.six.moves.urllib' in package 'urllib3' 1 package level up (tried urllib3.packages.six.moves.urllib,packages.six.moves.urllib).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py:10: Cannot find 'packages.six.moves.http_client' in package 'urllib3' 1 package level up (tried urllib3.packages.six.moves.http_client,packages.six.moves.http_client).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:46: Cannot find 'OpenSSL.SSL' in package 'urllib3.contrib' as absolute import (tried OpenSSL.SSL).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:46: Cannot find 'OpenSSL' in package 'urllib3.contrib' as absolute import (tried OpenSSL).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:47: Cannot find 'cryptography' in package 'urllib3.contrib' as absolute import (tried cryptography).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:48: Cannot find 'cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl' in package 'urllib3.contrib' as absolute import (tried cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:48: Cannot find 'cryptography.hazmat.backends' in package 'urllib3.contrib' as absolute import (tried cryptography.hazmat.backends).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:48: Cannot find 'cryptography.hazmat' in package 'urllib3.contrib' as absolute import (tried cryptography.hazmat).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:49: Cannot find 'cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.x509' in package 'urllib3.contrib' as absolute import (tried cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.x509).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:51: Cannot find 'cryptography.x509' in package 'urllib3.contrib' as absolute import (tried cryptography.x509).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:143: Cannot find 'cryptography.x509.extensions' in package 'urllib3.contrib' as absolute import (tried cryptography.x509.extensions).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:150: Cannot find 'OpenSSL.crypto' in package 'urllib3.contrib' as absolute import (tried OpenSSL.crypto).
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\Tearzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py:1: Cannot find 'sip' as relative or absolute import.
Error, implicit module 'sip' expected by 'PyQt5' not found.
```

This is what is it imports in the Python script.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys, os, subprocess, webbrowser, requests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sip` is different module. Install it via pip

`pip3 install -U sip`

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you've installed `sip` module by doing `pip install sip` and then make sure you use the pyqt plugin so the nuitka freezer will know how to scan the pyqt extension modules, ie:

```
nuitka main.py --standalone --recurse-all --plugin-enable=qt-plugins
```

If that doesn't work, make sure to open a github issue at https://github.com/kayhayen/Nuitka/issues filling up properly the issue template and we'll help you there, we're a friendly community, so proper bug reports will be well received ;D